# Thumbnails with Asp.net Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, thumbnails

Does anyone know of a way to display a thumbnail image from a byte array, or even better, a library that does this. Thanks

Comment: I added a new column to my table that is another blob but this one is for thumbnails and i use the technique i posted below to shrink the image

Comment: You're looking for the [ImageResizing.Net](http://imageresizing.net) library. It's free, and from what I know, the most popular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Thumbnail() {
            byte[] myByte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(location);
            Image i;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
                ms.Write(myByte , 0 , myByte.Length);
                i = Image.FromStream(ms);
            }
            return File(imageToByteArray(i.GetThumbnailImage(100 , 100 , () => false , IntPtr.Zero)) , "image/jpeg");
        }

        public byte[] imageToByteArray ( System.Drawing.Image imageIn ) {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms , System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
```

This is what i used. Instead of doing this each time i want a thumbnail, i created a new column in my table that was a varbinary and called that column each time i wanted a thumbnail.

Comment: GetThumbnailImage() produces very horrible results (although the GIF encoding will make it meaningless anyway). Also note that you're leaking a Image object (GDI handle), and No, the GC will not clean that up after you properly. [See this article](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/)

Answer (score 9):

With ASP.NET MVC 3 and WebMatrix we now have nice standard [WebImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webimage.aspx) class which has among others GetImageFromRequest, Resize, Crop and AddTextWatermark methods.

Answer (score 1):

I used this library to create thumbnail

https://github.com/terjetyl/Simple.ImageResizer

Example :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadFilePage(HttpPostedFileBase file, BannerCliente banner)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

            string crearRutaThumb = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Carpeta/" + banner.ClienteId), "thumbnail");
            Directory.CreateDirectory(crearRutaThumb);

            string rutaImagenOriginal = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Carpeta/" + banner.ClienteId), filename);

            var frerf = new ImageResizer(byteFile(rutaImagenOriginal));
            frerf.Resize(100, ImageEncoding.Jpg100);
            frerf.SaveToFile(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Carpeta/" + banner.ClienteId + "/thumbnail"), file.FileName));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            throw ex;
        }

        return View();
    }

    public byte[] byteFile(string fileName)
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

### The [open-source ImageResizing.Net library](http://imageresizing.net) is what you're looking for

It supports SQL, S3, and filesystem images, and allows resizing, cropping, rotation and many other manipulations.

It also offers an IVirtualImageProvider interface if you want to generate 'virtual images' instead of simply modifying existing ones.

NOTE: The SQL and S3 plugins are open-source, but have a $99 download fee (which includes both). The core library is free.